# Do I need a visa to transit Saudi Arabia?

Tags: transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I am travelling to Rome with five other family members from Bengaluru via Jeddah. I have a layover of 13.5 hours in Jeddah before I catch my connecting flight to Rome. I will not be leaving the airport in Jeddah. Do I need a transit visa for Saudi Arabia?